# Mysql - Multiple queries on a same table : get full single row reccord + get only next and previous ID + get siblings count based on parent_id

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to combine multiple queries called on a same table, and have absolutely no clue about how to achieve that.

I builded 3 queries, that I run one after the other. That works, but I'm wondering how to build thoses 3 queries on 1 run.

I - Get the full row

> SELECT * FROM `sp_products_items` WHERE id='.$id

II - Get the 'siblings' count

> SELECT count(*) FROM `sp_products_items` WHERE parent_id = $result->parent_id

III - Get previous and next ids (based on an counting field)

> SELECT
> (SELECT id FROM `sp_products_items` WHERE order= $result->order + 1) as next,
> (SELECT id FROM `sp_products_items` WHERE order= $result->order - 1) as previous

Any clue about how to achieve that ? Is it even possible ? Would it gain some performance or is it completely pointless to combine these in one run ?

I tried some nested selects, inner join, but with no success :(

Comment: This seems very unlikely to get the right id.  Please show us some sample data.  Also, which  $result are you hoping to use?

Comment: Your answer did the trick perfectly (I needed those datas to display a product of a given category, grab the product next and prev sibling of that category, and the total count contained in that category for navigation purpose)
I don't have permission to upvote your answer ...

Comment: Glad it worked.  Take the tutorial; it is an easy way to get 100 rep points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
SELECT n.id AS next,
       p.id AS previous,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sp_products_items WHERE id = a.parent ) AS ct
    FROM sp_products_items AS a
    LEFT JOIN sp_products_items AS n ON n.`order` = a.`order` + 1
    LEFT JOIN sp_products_items AS p ON p.`order` = a.`order` - 1
    WHERE a.id = $id
```

I used `LEFT` because the query might fall off the end.  Or there could be gaps in the numbering -- that is harder to account for.

I don't know the purpose of `COUNT(*)`, so I simply threw it in as extra info.

`sp_products_items` needs `INDEX(order)`

Comment: Hey, that's it ! (the purpose of the query is to get full data of a single product, categorized by a parent_id, get the total count of product childs of that same parent, and get the next and prev ID for navigation purpose (eg. "go to next"/"total number")
So for my purpose I just added "a.*, " juste after the first SELECT.